# Import HTML file to Katalon Recorder ( browser extension )

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder, katalon

I’m using Katalon Recorder ( browser extension ) and I have a file with test cases steps in .html, I can’t find a way to import these test cases to my test case

any suggestion on how I case import an HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You can import a test suite from the left side menu > Open Test Suite > Open KR Test Suite.
[image: screenshot of importing a test suite]

Just for your information, you can export a test suite from the three dots menu of the test suite > Download test suite

[image: screenshot of exporting a test suite]